# How to specify configuration for framework in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I cannot understand how to specify configuration for framework

For example, I have the project "MyProject.xcodeproj" with 3 configurations: **Debug**, **Stage** and **Production**. The project includes my framework "Xelby" so when I trying to build the project Xcode fails with error "Xelby framework not found".

Xelby has 2 configurations **Release** and **Debug**. So I don't understand how to specify **Release** configuration of Xelby on **Stage** configuration in my project.

I tried to add **Release** folder to **Framework Search Paths** but Xcode began to behave inappropriately, constantly hung up and other